# Not be able to log on to standard Neo4j Docker container - disable authentication form outside?

Tags: docker, neo4j, containers, kitematic

I'm using Kitematic to start my Docker containers. I'm trying to start the latest Neo4j container (3.2) and I cannot access the DB via the web browser because it requires authentication.

I tried to disable it via the environment variables (`NEO4J_AUTH`  `none`) but that doesn't solve the problem.The standard passw/user neo4j/neo4j doesn't work

Any ideas how to set the authentication via Kitematic?

[image: Web browser][image: Kitematic Variables]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem here but I can tell you why this is happening:

As you are using windows, you need to access Neo4J browser tool via the Docker Machine, that port forwards your request to the neo4j container.  The forwarded request is basically an authentication request.

The problem is CHROME does not allow unsecured transfer of credentials and the forwarded request fall into that category. This is an issue that comes from chrome and not the Neo4J server. I'm still trying to find an elegant way of solving this for my students that uses windows.

The easiest way would be to connect to the neo4j container directly (which can be done in linux and mac).

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally one of my student made it work.

make sure to publish both port 7687 and 7474 from your docker.
This way, both request will target `localhost` and the browser will stop complaining

here is a docker command showing how to publish both ports

```
docker run --rm --name neo4j_server -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 -d neo4j
```